# How do I parse an online JSON Dictionary source in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am trying to access and parse a JSON api that is a dictionary and does not have a structure that I am accustomed to creating a data model for in Swift.

The API: https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=52772

The contents:

```
{
    "meals": [{
        "idMeal": "52772",
        "strMeal": "Teriyaki Chicken Casserole",
        "strDrinkAlternate": null,
        "strCategory": "Chicken",
        "strArea": "Japanese",
        "strInstructions": "Preheat oven to 350\u00b0 F. Spray a 9x13-inch baking pan with non-stick spray.\r\nCombine soy sauce, \u00bd cup water, brown sugar, ginger and garlic in a small saucepan and cover. Bring to a boil over medium heat. Remove lid and cook for one minute once boiling.\r\nMeanwhile, stir together the corn starch and 2 tablespoons of water in a separate dish until smooth. Once sauce is boiling, add mixture to the saucepan and stir to combine. Cook until the sauce starts to thicken then remove from heat.\r\nPlace the chicken breasts in the prepared pan. Pour one cup of the sauce over top of chicken. Place chicken in oven and bake 35 minutes or until cooked through. Remove from oven and shred chicken in the dish using two forks.\r\n*Meanwhile, steam or cook the vegetables according to package directions.\r\nAdd the cooked vegetables and rice to the casserole dish with the chicken. Add most of the remaining sauce, reserving a bit to drizzle over the top when serving. Gently toss everything together in the casserole dish until combined. Return to oven and cook 15 minutes. Remove from oven and let stand 5 minutes before serving. Drizzle each serving with remaining sauce. Enjoy!",
        "strMealThumb": "https:\/\/www.themealdb.com\/images\/media\/meals\/wvpsxx1468256321.jpg",
        "strTags": "Meat,Casserole",
        "strYoutube": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=4aZr5hZXP_s",
        "strIngredient1": "soy sauce",
        "strIngredient2": "water",
        "strIngredient3": "brown sugar",
        "strIngredient4": "ground ginger",
        "strIngredient5": "minced garlic",
        "strIngredient6": "cornstarch",
        "strIngredient7": "chicken breasts",
        "strIngredient8": "stir-fry vegetables",
        "strIngredient9": "brown rice",
        "strIngredient10": "",
        "strIngredient11": "",
        "strIngredient12": "",
        "strIngredient13": "",
        "strIngredient14": "",
        "strIngredient15": "",
        "strIngredient16": null,
        "strIngredient17": null,
        "strIngredient18": null,
        "strIngredient19": null,
        "strIngredient20": null,
        "strMeasure1": "3\/4 cup",
        "strMeasure2": "1\/2 cup",
        "strMeasure3": "1\/4 cup",
        "strMeasure4": "1\/2 teaspoon",
        "strMeasure5": "1\/2 teaspoon",
        "strMeasure6": "4 Tablespoons",
        "strMeasure7": "2",
        "strMeasure8": "1 (12 oz.)",
        "strMeasure9": "3 cups",
        "strMeasure10": "",
        "strMeasure11": "",
        "strMeasure12": "",
        "strMeasure13": "",
        "strMeasure14": "",
        "strMeasure15": "",
        "strMeasure16": null,
        "strMeasure17": null,
        "strMeasure18": null,
        "strMeasure19": null,
        "strMeasure20": null,
        "strSource": null,
        "strImageSource": null,
        "strCreativeCommonsConfirmed": null,
        "dateModified": null
    }]
}
```

I have attempted to create a data model based on the inner contents like this:

```
struct MealDetail: Codable {
    let idMeal: String?
    let strMeal: String?
    let strDrinkAlternate: String?
    let strCategory: String?
    let strArea: String?
    let strInstructions: String?
    let strMealThumb: String?
    let strTags: String?
    let strYoutube: String?
    let strIngredient1: String?
    let strIngredient2: String?
    let strIngredient3: String?
    let strIngredient4: String?
    let strIngredient5: String?
    ...
}
```

And my code for parsing the JSON:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var mealDict: [String: String] = [:]
    
    var meal: Meal?
    var detail: MealDetail?
    var mealID: String = ""
    
    private var safeArea:  UILayoutGuide!
    private var urlString: String = ""
    
    private let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    private let contentView = UIView()
    private let mealTitle = UILabel()
    private let mealThumb = CustomImageView()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        safeArea = view.layoutMarginsGuide
        title = "\(mealID)"
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        setupScrollView()
        parseJSON()
        fetchMeal(detail!)
        
        setupImage()
        setupName()
        
    }
    
    private func parseJSON() {
    guard let mealID = meal?.idMeal else { return }
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=\(mealID)") else { return }

    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        parse(json: data)
    }
}

func parse(json: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    if let mealDetail = try? decoder.decode(MealDetail.self, from: json) {
        detail = mealDetail
    }
}

func fetchMeal(_ detail: MealDetail) {
    updateUI(title: detail.strMeal, thumb: detail.strMealThumb)
}

private func updateUI(title: String?, thumb: String?) {
    self.mealTitle.text = title
    self.mealThumb.image = UIImage(named: thumb ?? "noImageAvailable")
}
}
```

I do not have the option to modify the online content and all my attempts to parse this data return empty.

Any insights in how to properly parse this kind of content would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `try?` with `?`. Use a proper `do`/`try`/`catch` and see if there is an error...

Comment: What do you mean by "and all my attempts to parse this data return empty."? What exactly do you see? Are you aware that `fetchMeal` is empty?

Comment: And `detail = mealDetail.self` why self?

Comment: When I run the app, the detail view is empty, blank, no data.
MealDetail.self because Xcode complains if I don't add .self
I will try the do / try / catch

Comment: The `.self` is used to decode: `try? decoder.decode(MealDetail.self, from: json)`. After decoding, you have a variable of type `MealDetail`. Just write `detail = mealDetail`.

Comment: If I change to **detail = mealDetail** it returns nil.

Comment: I've updated the code to correct the fetchMeal function. The detail view now displays the placeholder image, but **detail** still returns nil so I am not pulling data from the API.

Comment: try https://app.quicktype.io/ to get Swift class/struct to parse JSON you have

Comment: QuickType gives the following struct: **struct MealDetail: Codable {
    let meals: [[String: String?]]
}** which still results in nil.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MealDetail` struct looks fine but that is not what your api is returning. Your api is returning an object with a top-level array of `MeailDetail` objects called `meals`.

You want to decode your data into a struct that looks like this:

```
struct Meals: Codable {
    let meals: [MealDetail]?
}
```

So your code should look something like this. Notice that the type passed to `decoder.decode(_:from:)` is `Meals.self`

```
func downloadMeals() throws -> Meals {
    guard let url = URL(
        string: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=52772"
    ) else { throw NSError(domain: "badURL", code: 100) }

    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try decoder.decode(Meals.self, from: data)
}
```